# Docker command not able to pass parameter at runtime to a appConfig.json file

Tags: angularjs, docker

Hi i am new to docker(version 19.03.8) and basically I have an angularjs project(dummyPoject) which contains appConfig.json file with the following path `dummyPoject\src\assets\conf\appConfig.json`. The json file contains the following variable:

```
{
  "baseUrl": "MAPPED-URL"
}
```

Basically I want to override the **MAPPED-URL**  properties with the one that i am sending while executing docker command.

Based on the online documentation I found out that it can be passed as environment variable while running the docker command please find below:

```
docker run -e baseUrl=http://localhost:8081/dummyUrl/ -p 8000:8080 -d --name cms test:1.0
```

I was expecting that MAPPED-URL will change to http://localhost:8081/dummyUrl/ but it is not the case.
Anything I am missing here please?

Answer (score 0):

By adding `-e baseUrl=http://localhost:8081/dummyUrl/` to `docker run` you have successfully added a environment variable to your docker container. But this value will not magically replace values in your `appConfig.json` file.

You will need some sort of script that extracts the baseUrl variable from environment and replaces the value in the script. This could be done using a bash script which runs when the container starts and replaces the line `"baseUrl": "MAPPED-URL"` using the environment variable you added.

**Update:**

This question inspired me to create a small Node.js package command line package that should help solve your issue. The package is called [replace-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-env)

You can add `replace-env` to your package.json dependencies. You can then run the command as part of your Dockerfile build process, or you can have it modify the file at runtime by customizing your `CMD` instruction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply is there an online tutorial I can follow to implement your suggested answer please?

Comment: You can try this tutorial https://kaijento.github.io/2017/03/26/bash-injecting-shell-variables-into-a-file/  
After creating the Bash script you should add the existing command that starts the container to end of the script and then set the script as the CMD like so: `CMD bash_script.sh`